# Django complex query through builder

Tags: django, django-orm, query-builder

I have not been able to make a complex query using ORM for some time. I know that this is possible, so I will forgive help.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    no matter

class Competition(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(to='game.Game', verbose_name=_('game'), related_name='competitions',
                         on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class User(models.Mode):
    no matter

class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class BalanceTransaction(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (TYPE_COMMISSION, _('commission')),
    }
    competition = models.ForeignKey(to='competition.Competition', verbose_name=_('competition'), related_name='transactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.ForeignKey(to=Balance, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transactions')
    amount = models.DecimalField(_('Transaction amount'), default='0.0', max_digits=28, decimal_places=18,
                             null=False, blank=False)

    type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=10, default=TYPE_DEPOSIT, choices=TYPES, null=False, blank=False
```

I have to return a queryset of games, where each element will have an additional "income" field that stores the sum of all transactions of this game with the type "commission"

```
    Game.objects.filter(publisher__owner=self.request.user.pk).annotate(
    income=Sum(Case(
        When(
            Q(publisher__owner__balance__transactions__type=BalanceTransaction.TYPE_COMMISSION),
            then=???,
        )
    ))
```

It seems that this way it will not be possible and I have to use subquery, but so far I haven't succeeded.

Comment: I forgot to add a field to the BalanceTransaction
competition = models.ForeignKey(to='competition.Competition', verbose_name=_('competition'),
                                    related_name='transactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need subqueries or case, just a standard filter.

```
Game.objects.filter(publisher__owner=self.request.user.pk).filter(
    publisher__owner__balance__transactions__type=BalanceTransaction.TYPE_COMMISSION
).annotate(
    income=Sum('publisher__owner__balance__transactions__amount)
)
```

See [order of annotate and filter clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) for an explanation about why this works.

Comment: Each transaction is associated with a competition. It is also associated with the game. We need transaction amounts with the type of "commission" for each game, and not just the sum of all transactions of this type.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You don't have a relationship between Game and Transaction, only the indirect one that goes via publisher__owner. Please can you edit your question with the full models.

Comment: I wrote a comment under the main post, you might not notice it.

Comment: Yes OK but that is to Competition, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with this. Where is the relation to Game?

Comment: BalanceTransaction has a ForeignKey to Competition. Competition has a ForeignKey to Game.

Comment: OK, so won't changing 'publisher__owner__balance' to 'competition__transactions' in both cases work?

Comment: Thank you, I was inattentive